# table view drill down succession

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, oop

I need to create a drill down effect with my table views that will expand four table views deep for each of my original cells in my master table view. So far i was successful in populating the master view, and second table view accordingly with this Object Oriented Method, here is the code in my master table view:

```
 class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    let aSport:[Sport] = {
        var basketball = Sport()
        basketball.name = "Basketball"
        basketball.sportCategories = {
            var temp = ["International Basketball","Wheelchair Basketball","Beach Basketball","Deaf Basketball","Dwarf Basketball"]
            temp.sort(<)
            return temp
            }()

        var golf = Sport()
        golf.name = "Golf"
        golf.sportCategories = {
            var temp = ["Miniature Golf","Dart Golf","Sholf","Disc Golf","Footgolf"]
            temp.sort(<)
            return temp
            }()

        var football = Sport()
        football.name = "Football"
        football.sportCategories = {
            var temp = ["Flag Football","Indoor Football","Arena Football","Non-Tackle Football","Paper Football"]
            temp.sort(<)
            return temp
            }()

        var swimming = Sport()
        swimming.name = "Swimming"
        swimming.sportCategories = {
            var temp = ["Competitive Swimming","Synchronized Swimming","Duo Swimming","Relay Swimming"]
            temp.sort(<)
            return temp
            }()

        return  [basketball,golf,football,swimming]
        }()

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return aSport.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = aSport[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let row = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)?.row
        let detail = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondTableViewController
        detail.selectedSport = aSport[row!]
    }


}


class Sport {

    var name: String = "sport name"
    var sportCategories: NSArray = ["variations of selected sport"]
    var detailText: NSArray = ["little description of sport"]

}
```

here is the code in my second table view controller:

```
class SecondTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var selectedSport = Sport();


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return selectedSport.sportCategories.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Custom", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text = selectedSport.sportCategories[indexPath.row] as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = selectedSport.detailText[indexPath.row] as? String
    return cell
}

}
```

here are screenshots from my simulator so you get a visual:

https://40.media.tumblr.com/6ee47f49c2b223b514f8067c68ac6af1/tumblr_nqbe74HYGo1tupbydo1_500.png

when basketball is selected:

https://41.media.tumblr.com/ced0ee2ff111a557ec3c21f1fb765adf/tumblr_nqbe74HYGo1tupbydo2_500.png

Now as you can see, i was able to populate the first two views by creating a custom class, creating custom objects of that class and using the properties within the class. Now my dilemma is, each of the "sportCategories" properties have their OWN table views to expand to which will consist of a whole list of names of players in that respective sport. Now what method should i go about doing this? should i create a whole new class in my second table view controller to give the sportsCategories their own properties? or is there a way i can already expand off the work I've already done? a more efficient way?

Comment: Rather than hardcoding it all you should use a data source like a plist, Core Data, json file, etc. Then you don't really care about the raw data as such, it's all generic and hierarchy is determined by the data source.

Comment: can you elaborate further? that answer is just a little cloudy to me @cjnevin

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't an answer just a comment. You would create a hierarchy, then simply represent the hierarchy in your code. Apple has an example, albeit deprecated, it should help you figure it out... https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007416

Comment: yeah its extremely depreciated, and i don't really do to well comprehending obj c @cjnevin

Comment: All you really need is a parent-child hierarchy, pretty simple to set one up. In Swift: let items = ["Parent A": ["A", "B", "C"], "Parent B": ["D", "E", "F"]]...Your original data source would be just the top level 'keys' - this is a Dictionary containing an Array for each key... Now when you tap on Parent A you present a view controller with a data source of A, B, C (items["Parent A"]). This is the most simple example I can give ignoring all stored data hierarchies common to iOS.

Comment: If you wanted to store this Dictionary, you could write to/read from a plist without much trouble (they share the same format - key:value for Basic types).

Comment: oh ok i see, that makes sense. however can you begin a chat with me? i just have a few inquiries to this method @cjnevin